# How to solve this circular import problem?

Tags: python

I have a library like this. wckg is the library name

```
wckg:
  __init__.py
  api/wckg_api.py
```

In `__init__.py`, I import the `wckg_api` scope and have an enum defined:

```
from wckg.api import wckg_api
class RelType(Enum):
   a = 1
   b = 2

WCKG = wckg_api.Wckg()
```

In `api/wckg_api.py`:

```
from wckg import RelType
   class Wckg(object):
     pass
```

As you can see,  from `wckg_api.py`, it imports `RelType` from `__init__`, and at the same time it imports  `wckg_api` from from `wckg.api.py` to create the `Wckg` object. This is circular and it reports an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RelType' from 'wckg' (/Users/comin/nlpc/wckg/wckg/**init**.py)

Is there a way to resolve this issue? **init** defined the interfaces and wckg_api.py is supposed to define the implementations of interfaces. I dont' want to define the constant RelType in wckg_api.py because I don't want users to import those constant types when users call a function from **init**.  Those types can be immediately available to users. But since **init** also need to import something from wckg_api.py, it creates this circular import issue.

Is this a typical issue?

Comment: put `RelType` in a different file than `__init__.py`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: @PaulH, by defining it in __init__,py, uses don't have to import. Is that right? Is this good practice?

Comment: you import it into the `__init__.py` file from the other file

Comment: here's a typical `__init__.py` file that i've written: https://github.com/phobson/paramnormal/blob/master/paramnormal/__init__.py

Comment: @PaulH I will try that.

Comment: @PaulH, I tried defining the RelType in another file and then import it from __init__. However, when users call a function from __init__ that uses RelType as an argument type, RelType still has to be imported first. Ideally, I want users only need to import the interface library name 'wckg', without needing to import anything else. Is that possible?

Comment: yes. that's exactly what the `__init__.py` file is for.

Answer (score 1):

I would fix this like that:

```
wckg:
  __init__.py
  api/wckg_api.py
  api/_rel_type.py
```

api/wckg_api.py:

```py
from ._rel_type import RelType

class Wckg(object):
    pass
```

api/_rel_type.py:

```py
class RelType(Enum):
   a = 1
   b = 2
```

and under `__init__.py`:

```py
from wckg.api import wckg_api, RelType

WCKG = wckg_api.Wckg()
```

Comment: I tried. When user call a function that needs RelType as function argument, he still has to import RelType from _rel_type.py. Ideally, I only want users to import 'wckg' then he can start to use all functions defined in it.

Comment: The user can now import it from `wckg` directly. It's possible because the `__init__.py` imports it.

Comment: I mean I tried, but found that users have to do "import wckg" and also do 'from rel_type import RelType'. Without the second import, it still complains the missing 'RelType'. Is this expcted?  I dont' want users to import RelType from either __init__ or rel_type.py. I want it to be available automatically, so that users only need to 'import wckg'. Is that possible?

Comment: @marlon who are the users in this case? have they installed your package via a `setup.py` file (or a wheel or conda package) because that's what should be happening. It sounds like you're describing developers and that's exactly what should be happening

Comment: @PaulH, I am talking about end users. not developers. Yes, they install through pip set.py and import the library name 'wckg', then I hope they can call any function defined in the __init__.py, without requiring them to import individually type like 'RelType'. Is that possible?

Comment: if you import `RelType` directly in your `__init__` file, it will be available to end users after they import your package (e.g., `import wckg; wckg.RelType`)

Comment: OK。 I see, users also need to import wckg.RelType. I thought 'RelType' can be automatically available after users 'import wckg' only. That's why initially I tried to define RelType in __init__.py to hope  the need of 'import RelType' can be eliminated.

Comment: no. if `RelType` is brought directly into `__init__.py`, importing the package will be enough