# How to avoid circular imports in Python without merge into a single file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, circular-dependency

Here are my files:

```
- ./
    - child.py
    - parent.py
    - main.py
```

#### `child.py`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from parent import Parent

@dataclass
class Child:
    name: str

    def get_mother(self) -> Parent:
        # simulating query from database...
        return Parent(
            name="Jane",
            children=[
                Child(self.name),
                Child("Alice"),
                Child("Bob"),
            ],
        )
```

#### `parent.py`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from child import Child


@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    children: list[Child]
```

#### `main.py`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from child import Child

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Charles = Child("Charles")
    print(f"{Charles}'s mother is {Charles.get_mother()}")
```

### Question

How can I resolve this circular import issue without merge the 2 files.

Running `main.py` raises an exception

```py
python main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\circular_import\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from child import Child
```

Then, I have changed `from xx import XX`  to `import xx` in all 3 files. However, it does not resolve the issue.

```py
python main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\circular_import\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import child
  File "d:\circular_import\child.py", line 3, in <module>
    import parent
  File "d:\circular_import\parent.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Parent:
  File "d:\circular_import\parent.py", line 9, in Parent
    children: list[child.Child]
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'child' has no attribute 'Child' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

If I merge `parents.py` and `child.py` into one file, it does solve the issue. But this is an less ideal solution.

```py
python main.py

Child(name='Charles')'s mother is Parent(name='Jane', children=[Child(name='Charles'), Child(name='Alice'), Child(name='Bob')])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541779/125562)

The idea is to do one of imports lazily from inside a method.
This will require relaxing some type declarations though.

```
    def get_mother(self):
        from parent import Parent
        # simulating query from database...
        return Parent(
            name="Jane",
            children=[
                Child(self.name),
                Child("Alice"),
                Child("Bob"),
            ],
        )
```

Comment: You can use modules such as **fileinput**, **shutil**, or **glob** to merge .py files in one file.
Did you try this method as a professional one?
although these modules act in different ways and I don't know what is your perspective to achieve

Comment: @Elnaz why would merging files help? The question is how to avoid the merge.

Comment: My advice was about how to not merge in circular way

Answer (score 0):

Since you only use them for type hints you only need to import them when type checking.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from child import Child

@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    children: "list[Child]"
```

This will not create a circular import at runtime, but still type hint properly.

Child has a "genuine" dependency on parent so it will need a normal import